# How to make an eloquent query that excludes custom attributes set to append a model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to make an eloquent query that excludes all custom attributes appended to that model?

Here is what I tried:

```
User::all(['first_name', 'last_name', 'id']);
```

This works as far as eliminating the original fields that belong to the table in the results of the query, but the custom attributes that are appended are still executed and appended to the results of my query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get back a bunch of User models that only have those attributes, correct?

So  `User::select(['first_name','last_name','id'])->get();` is probably what you're looking for.

Let me know if I am mistaken as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Not quite. This still retrieves all the 'appends' or custom attributes on the model, and not just the selected columns.